# react native state changing problem in picker

Tags: react-native, expo

In react native picker, state is not changing between parent and psychiatrist. Is it only going to parent button even if we select psychiatrist?

```
               <Picker style = {styles.input1}
                  selectedValue={this.state.selectedValue}
                  onValueChange={(itemValue, itemIndex) =>
                    this.setState({designation: itemValue})
                  }>
                  <Picker.Item label="Parent" value="Parent" />
                  <Picker.Item label="Psychiatrist" value="Psychiatrist" />
                  <Picker.Item label="NA" value="NA" />
                </Picker>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not setting the right state in the selected value. Set the selected value to `this.state.designation`:

```
                <Picker style = {styles.input1}
                  selectedValue={this.state.designation}
                  onValueChange={(itemValue, itemIndex) =>
                    this.setState({designation: itemValue})
                  }>
                  <Picker.Item label="Parent" value="Parent" />
                  <Picker.Item label="Psychiatrist" value="Psychiatrist" />
                  <Picker.Item label="NA" value="NA" />
                </Picker>
```

Answer (score 0):

In your onValueChange you are settingState "designation" ,instead you should change state of the selectedValue of the picker : "selectedValue".

```
<Picker style = {styles.input1}
   selectedValue={this.state.selectedValue}
   onValueChange={(itemValue, itemIndex) =>
   this.setState({selectedValue: itemValue})
   }>
   <Picker.Item label="Parent" value="Parent" />
   <Picker.Item label="Psychiatrist" value="Psychiatrist" />
   <Picker.Item label="NA" value="NA" />
</Picker>
```